# Is order of storing values to localStorage synchronous?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Sorry for my horrible English.

I am using localStorage to store some properties. Every property has its own key and value, keys and values are generated dynamically. So I do not know how many of them will be.

On page1 all properties are saved (with one click).

On page2 I call "storage" event. I need to read all keys and values and re-render content of page using these.

Problem is that "storage" event fires for every key/value pair. And I do not want to re-render content of page2 for every key/value pair. I want to wait untill all properties are saved on page1 and then re-render content of page2.

So I need to be sure that all properties were saved on page1 and AFTER that I need to read them on page 2.

My question: is storing process for localStorage synchronous? 
"Synchronous" means for me that only one setItem command is executed at the same time and all setItem commands are executed in exact order that I wrote. 
So when I will write:

```
(loop start)    
localStorage.setItem("bar1", foo1)
localStorage.setItem("bar2", foo2)
...
localStorage.setItem("bar100", foo100)
(loop end)
```

can I be sure, that ALL items were saved BEFORE ("bar100", foo100)?

Or there can be any problem and ("bar100", foo100) may be saved before any previous item?

Alex

Comment: Yes. JavaScript itself is one-thread language. Program executes from 1 line, 2 line and so on.

Comment: If it doesn't have a callback, it's generally synchronous, and the localStorage methods are synchronous, so you can be sure the code executed in order, the question is, why would it matter what order it was written in. I suspect you're expecting order in the keys in the object that is localStorage, and ***that*** you won't have, as there is no order in objects.

Comment: If you want a bunch of things serialized in order, then put them all in an array, call JSON.stringify on the array and save that.  localStorage items does not have an innate order.

Comment: and per @jfriend00 suggestion , it's far less work to get or save one object than writing a whole bunch of individual items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the W3C specification:

> Whenever the properties of a localStorage attribute's Storage object are to be examined, returned, set, or deleted, whether as part of a direct property access, when checking for the presence of a property, during property enumeration, when determining the number of properties present, or as part of the execution of any of the methods or attributes defined on the Storage interface, the user agent must first obtain the storage mutex.

This means that it is running in a synchronous manner, however, that doesn't guarantee the order of the stored items after a page reload.

But to answer your question, yes, `"bar100"` will be written to local storage last.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It was helpful. I do not care of order of stored items after page reload,  only thing I need is proper sync between browser tabs/windows. So I will use use last stored item as a indicator that says "all previsous items were saved, page2 can execute code".